# when a button is "active", I want to make all images to the picture for "active"

Tags: html, css

I created a flexible button made of three parts.
I made three parts from one picture. I think it is called "sprite" or something

Here is the css.

```
.commonButtonLeft, .commonButtonContent, .commonButtonRight
{
    background-image:url(img/commonbutton.png);
}

.commonButtonLeft
{
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left;
    width:14px;
}

.commonButtonContent
{
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    text-align:center;
}

.commonButtonRight
{
    height:40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right;
    width:14px;
    float:left;
}
```

Now I created another picture "commonbutton_onclick.png" for the clicked button.
And I added the following class.

```
.commonButtonLeft:active, .commonButtonContent:active, .commonButtonRight:active
{
    background-image:url(img/commonbutton_onclick.png);
}
```

It didn't work well.
When I click the area ".commonButtonContent", the area only becomes the active picture.
I want to make all classes to be "commonbutton_onclick.png".
I can not use css3 in this case by the way.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, if the items are divs, you'll need to use `:hover`, not `:active`.

Perhaps but the entire button in a single div (class commonButton). this way you can do something like this. This will cause all 3 divs to change when the container is hovered anywhere, rather than targeting the hovering of a single piece.

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kcv3h/2/) to demonstrate.

```
.commonButton .commonButtonLeft
{
    ...
}
.commonButton .commonButtonRight
{
    ...
}
.commonButton .commonButtonContent
{
    ...
}

.commonButton:hover .commonButtonLeft
{
    ...
}
.commonButton:hover .commonButtonRight
{
    ...
}
.commonButton:hover .commonButtonContent
{
    ...
}
```